# Cannot load other profile on my jhipster application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jhipster

I upgraded my jhipster project from 5.8.2 to 6.5.1, and now, I can not deploy on Heroku ([unable to deploy to heroku since jhipster update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411150/unable-to-deploy-to-heroku-since-jhipster-update))

I thought it was problem on linking database, suddenly I try to launch my app with good profile

My app has 3 profiles 
- dev
- int (test environment)
- prod

if I launch

```
./gradlew -Pint
```

or

```
 ./gradlew -Pprod
```

I have this result

```
The following profiles are active: prod
2019-12-26 11:53:38.867  WARN 16584 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in file [D:\workspace\yvidya\build\classes\java\main\fr\yoni\yvidya\repository\CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1a5b7394' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1a5b7394': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [fr/yoni/yvidya/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2019-12-26 11:53:38.908 ERROR 16584 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

In my folder "resources/config" folder, I have application-int.yml and application-prod.yml. Those files are OK before upgrade

And in my build.gradle, I have :

```
if (project.hasProperty("prod")) {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_prod.gradle"
} else if (project.hasProperty("int")) {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_int.gradle"
} else {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_dev.gradle"
}
```

gradle files config per environment exist.

What's my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error

in properties database file I have :

```
jdbc:postgres://e
```

And the good propertie is :

```
jdbc:postgresql://e
```